# Problem with unique html() jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery function, that if it will hit specific class is wrapping it with some oter divs.

```
(document).ready(function(){
   var Text = $('.bd_box_cont').html();
   $('.bd_box_cont').html(" 
      <div class='bd_box_tl'><div class='bd_box_rt'>" + Text +"</div></div>

   ");
)}
```

Only problem is that I have more then one container on my site, and it is putting this same html to every one of them.

How can I return var Text for specific container?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pay more attention to the jquery selectors - http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors
There are a lot of ways to get your object based on a filter.

```
$('.bd_box_cont:first').html
     ("       <div class='bd_box_tl'><div class='bd_box_rt'>" + Text +"</div></div>   
");
```

for example gets your first container

Answer (score 1):

You use the class functions of jquery (so every div with the class bd_box_cont gets that html.
When you only want one div to have that html, just use ids (#bd_box_cont).html... rest of you code.

Comment: but then page will not valid with w3c

Comment: True but that's because you can have only one div with a specified ID.
Else you need to use the method described b(momentarily bellow of Svetlozar Angelov). Here you define it with the class method only you define that you only want to put the html in the first occurrence of that class

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more easily using [.wrapInner()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapInner):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.bd_box_cont').wrapInner("<div class='bd_box_tl'><div class='bd_box_rt'></div></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @greg said use `wrapInner()`. For future reference, if you want to do something to each item of an element where one of the native functions won't suffice, use `each()`:

```
$('.bd_box_cont').each(function() {
  this_element = $(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use something like this (let's say you want to change i.e. second container):

```
var container = $('.bd_box_cont').get(1);
var Text = $(container).html();
$(container).html(" 
  <div class='bd_box_tl'><div class='bd_box_rt'>" + Text +"</div></div>
");
```

another option that does the same:

```
var container = $('.bd_box_cont:eq(1)');
var Text = container.html();
container.html(" 
  <div class='bd_box_tl'><div class='bd_box_rt'>" + Text +"</div></div>
");
```